# How do I copy a leaf and make it look different and connect with another leaf at a certain point via scripting?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I copy a leaf and make it look different(scale, size, seeds if there are any?) and connect with another leaf at a certain point via scripting?

Here's my leaf model:

[image]

Here's the result I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You can set the Origin point to be the bottom of the stem so that you can rotate and position the leaf as required. You can certainly write Python that will scale randomly a selection of objects. Try and write what you need and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: The question IS how to write it. How to copy and correctly place one leaf with another so their stems are connected at one point using python is a first question. 2nd question is how do I randomize them using python. I'm asking for a script example @rob

Comment: Here’s a addon I made that kinda does what you want. https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-texplane-foliage-generator/701480

Comment: @AFWS I'm working with blender 2.8

Comment: If it will do what you need, I can finish updating for 2.8. I started working on it on a early version of 2.8.

Comment: @AFWS I guess it kinda does what I want, but I'm not sure, and I didn't get how to use it after a brief look